# Does the completion of $C[0,1]$ equipped with esssup norm is $L^\infty[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis

Don't forget  the completion of $C[0,1]$ equipped with $||*||_p$ norm is $L^p[0,1]$ for $1\leq p<\infty$.

first, we know $C[0,1]$ equipped with **sup norm** is complete.

second, we know  $L^\infty[0,1]$ equipped with **esssup norm** is complete.

Last, we konw **sup norm = esssup norm**  for $C[0,1]$, and $C[0,1]\subset L^\infty[0,1]$.

So the question arises,

Does the completion of $C[0,1]$ equipped with **esssup norm** is $L^\infty[0,1]$?

I think the answer is obviously **no**, but the teacher say "yes" in the class, I doubt it.

Comment: What are your own thoughts on this?  [Show](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/) [your work](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/)!  Also, please use [MathJax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $C[0,1] $ is closed in the $\infty$ norm.

Comment: I updated something, can you give more comments, please?@
user10354138

Comment: Indeed $C[0,1]$ is closed and not the whole of $L^\infty[0,1]$.  For example, $1_{[0,\frac12]}$ is in $L^\infty[0,1]$ (since it is the indicator function of a closed set so measurable and only takes two values $\{0,1\}$ so bounded) but is of distance $\geq\frac12$ from any point of $C[0,1]$.

Comment: In metric spaces *complete* subspaces are closed, thus "no".

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in a Banach space, a subset is closed if, and only if it is complete.

Take an arbitrary Cauchy sequence $(f_n)$ in $C[0,1]$ with respect to the $L^\infty$-norm. Since the $L^\infty$-norm $\|.\|_{L^\infty}$ agrees with the sup norm $\|.\|_u$ on the space of continuous functions, $(f_n)$ is also a Cauchy sequence in $C[0,1]$ endowed with $\|.\|_u$ (which is complete). Therefore $f_n$ converges to a certain continuous function $f$ with respect to $\|.\|_u$.

Now we have $\|f_n-f\|_u = \|f_n-f\|_{L^\infty} \to 0$ and $(f_n)$ converges in $(C[0,1],\|.\|_{L^\infty})$.

$C[0,1]$ is complete in $L^\infty[0,1]$, hence closed.